# Replace multiple captured groups in regex

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, replace, capture-group

VB2005: I've been looking at regex for some hours now and cant seem to get my head around the .Replace for my case. I'm looking for two fields and then I want to replace those fields with new values. So my string looks like so:

```
Dim myInputString as string ="RTEMP                 MIN<240  MAX<800"
```

My regex is

```
dim ptn as string = "RTEMP\s{17}MIN<(?<min>(\d|\s){1,3})\s{1,3}MAX<(?<max>(\d|\s){1,3})\s{1,12}"
Dim MyRegex As Regex = New Regex(ptn, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

and that works well and it captures my two fields.
Now I have new values

```
dim newMin as integer = 300
dim newMax as integer = 999
```

But cant seem to figure out how to replace the two values in one swoop

```
Dim result As String = MyRegex.Replace(myInputString, MyRegexReplace)
```

What do I put in MyRegexReplace? This is a simple two value replace but Im going to have possibly more so was thinking there has got to be a way to do this but need help.

Thanks
AGP

Comment: It's a bit hacky, but you could do `"(RTEMP\s{17}MIN<)(...)(\s{1,3}MAX<)(...)(\s{1,12})"` and replace with `"\1{newMin}\3{newMax}\5"`, where you've substituted newMin & newMax in.

Comment: so this takes the first part, adds new value, middle part, adds new value, and last part? yeah i think i see how it works. but i will need to do this for 20 fields. this was just a small example. ill try it though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 2 distinct values to swap into those 2 fields, wouldn't you want to use 2 separate Regex operations?

But if you want to use one Regex operation, you could use a MatchEvaluator:

```
Dim result As string = MyRegex.Replace(myInputString, ReplaceField)

Private Function ReplaceField(match As Match) As String
    ' Use the Index property of the Match to determine what value to use as replacement
End Function
```

Comment: yeah i could use two regex but this is a small example of what i have to do. in the end I am replacing 20 fields with new values. let me try this method and see how it pans out.